# How to filter two categories on dashboard? Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 sheets I'd like to filter on the dashboard: months, supervisor name, and supervisee name. What I would like to do is have the functionality to click on a month, and have everything filter. I'd also like to click on the supervisor and supervisee, and have it do the same thing.

The problem is, that my supervisees keep disappearing every time I select a supervisor. The data is set up as a hierarchy within tableau and is on a corresponding line in the original hard data. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook? Might be easier for us to understand what's going on.

Comment: plz share more details

Comment: Can you post some sample data?